# Expiring Certificate on Enterprise app (IOS)

Tags: ios, certificate, enterprise, software-distribution

I have an enterprise app out in the field signed with a distribution certificate 3 years ago that is due to expire next month. Ideally I would like to not have to redeploy my app to my users and according to the apple docs [Re-Creating Certificates and Updating Related Provisioning Profiles](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW29),  it appears I can create a new dist cert, update my profile with the new cert and my app out in the field will not be effected. I have read some conflicting posts on the matter from a few years ago now admittedly that say I will need to re-deploy my enterprise app so was wondering would anyone be able to confirm for me what teh latest state of play is.

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need to redeploy an app if your `bundler identifier` is same.

You can revoke current certificate and create a new one. This action can result into 'stop' usage of app in mobile device (if or when it has connection to apple server). The reason for this is, user needs to accept/trust developer of new certificate from device's settings.

Once user accepts/trust new certificate, your app will continue working as it was.

You can ask me, if you still have any confusion or problem in understanding this scenario.

Recently, I practically tested this scenario for one of my enterprise app and it was successful.

Hope it would work for you also !!!